# Outlook sends uninvited images as attachments

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, attachments

Outlook is always sending along 2 pictures (image001.png and image002.gif) with my mails. Even if I don't attach any images.

How do I fix this?

[screenshot of email http://lh5.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/SznrvCGr93I/AAAAAAAAC14/XYOtNFV2Z_w/s800/gmail.png](http://lh5.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/SznrvCGr93I/AAAAAAAAC14/XYOtNFV2Z_w/s800/gmail.png)
Thanks.

## EDIT - SIGNATURE

The HTML of my signature:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<HTML xmlns:o = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"><HEAD><TITLE>Company default Signature</TITLE>
<META content="text/html; charset=windows-1252" http-equiv=Content-Type>
<META name=GENERATOR content="MSHTML 8.00.6001.18854"></HEAD>
<BODY>
<DIV align=left><FONT color=navy size=2 face=Arial><SPAN 
style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: navy; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">
<P class=MsoNormal align=left><BR>Cordialement,&nbsp;</SPAN></FONT><FONT 
color=navy size=2 face=Arial><SPAN 
style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: navy; FONT-SIZE: 10pt"><o:p>&nbsp;</o:p></SPAN></FONT></P>
<P class=MsoNormal><FONT color=navy size=2 face=Arial><SPAN 
style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: navy; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">Firstname 
LASTNAME<BR></SPAN></FONT><FONT color=navy size=2 face=Arial><SPAN 
style="FONT-FAMILY: Arial; COLOR: navy; FONT-SIZE: 10pt">COMPANY 
Name<o:p></o:p></SPAN></FONT></P></DIV></BODY></HTML>
```

## EDIT 2 - STATIONERY

I **don't** use stationery format:

[alt text http://lh3.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/SzoPJy2t25I/AAAAAAAAC2U/t1cue8G48EE/s800/stationery.png](http://lh3.ggpht.com/_1TPOP7DzY1E/SzoPJy2t25I/AAAAAAAAC2U/t1cue8G48EE/s800/stationery.png)

## EDIT 3 - HTML

If I delete the signature (Ctrl+A, Del) in the **HTML mode** the images always appear. If I use the signature in **text only mode**, the images disappears...

Comment: Are you using a custom signature in outlook?

Comment: @klausbyskov: Yes... but there is only some HTML text, no images.

Comment: Please post the HTML from your signature.

Comment: Are you using the "stationery" feature?

Comment: if i may ask, which email service are you using?

Comment: @Molly: what do you mean? this is a corporate Microsoft Exchange Server... :")

Comment: so you email address is something like serhio@yourcompany.com? that's all i wanted to know.

Comment: @molly: Yes, exactly.

Comment: If you don't use the signature does it still happen? Could it be something corporate is adding to all outgoing e-mail?

Comment: @Al Everett: "If I don't use signature"... So, if this mean that I delete the signature (Ctrl+A, Del) the images always appear. If I use the signature in text only mode, the images disappears...

Comment: If you look at the email in your Sent Items are the pictures attached?

Comment: @Shevek, no I don't see any picture attached. However, if I send message even in text mode I receive a 0 Kb attachement "winmail.dat" in Google. Recieving the same message in outlook (pop.google) I don't recieve anything in attachement.

Comment: If there is nothing attached on the sent item then it's possibly something your mail server is doing on its way out

Comment: @Shevek: or Outlook just hides files automatically attached by itself. see my comment on Grizly's answer.

Comment: Sadly this question has broken images now. @serhio if you are still around, do you have these screenshots?

Answer (score 2):

Answers to both your questions:

### Unwanted attachments like image001.gif:

Outlook is very 'smart':

> How can I prevent an Internet image from being embedded in the
>   message?
>
> After creating a signature with a link to an Internet image,
>   you might experience that the image still gets embedded in the message
>   itself.
>
> Outlook has an option to control to what should happen with
>   linked images; they can either stay linked or Outlook can embed them
>   in the message upon sending.
>
> In Outlook 2003 you can find the option
>   under; Tools-> Options…-> tab Mail Format-> button Internet Format->
>   disable the option: "When an HTML message contains pictures located on
>   the Internet, send a copy of the pictures instead of the reference to
>   the location."
>
> In Outlook 2007 and Outlook 2010, this option can only
>   be modified via the Registry;
>
> Key Outlook 2007: 
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
>
> Key Outlook 2010: 
>   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\Options\Mail
>
> Value name; **Send Pictures With Document Value: 0** (REG_DWORD)
>
> With a value of 1 or if the value name is missing, you’ll include the picture with the
>   message instead of as a link.  If the value is set to 0 you’ll send a
>   link.
>
> Note: The value name contains spaces and capital letters; you
>   must include these as well.

This was copy/pasted from:

[How can I prevent an Internet image from being embedded in the message? http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/how-to-insert-picture-in-outlook-2010-signature/b9d94d8b-3e66-4885-b30f-79135029d6e4](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-outlook/how-to-insert-picture-in-outlook-2010-signature/b9d94d8b-3e66-4885-b30f-79135029d6e4)

### The winmail.dat attachment:

MS Exchange is very 'smart':

> When an end user sends mail to the Internet from an Exchange Windows
>   or Outlook client, a file attachment called Winmail.dat may be
>   automatically added to the end of the message if the recipient's
>   client cannot receive messages in Rich Text Format (RTF). The
>   Winmail.dat file contains Exchange Server RTF information for the
>   message, and may appear to the recipient as a binary file. It is not
>   useful to non-Exchange Server recipients.
>
> To control **whether or not to send messages in RTF**, follow the option
>   that best meets your situation:
>   ...
>   Rest can be found on:
>   [How to Prevent the Winmail.dat File from Being Sent to Internet Users
>   http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138053](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/138053)

---

It took me way to long to find this information, i hope this will help the next information seeker :)

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using stationary on your emails (backgrounds on your emails). You will need to disable this feature from your emails if you want to stop having attachments sent with every single email you send.

Comment: take a look at my Edit 2, apparently I don't use a stationery format (<Aucun> = <None>)

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete the folder: c:\documents and settings\username\application data\microsoft\signatures, then create a new sig in outlook. (it uses that folder)
2. Turn off "Word as editor(1)", test, revert change.. sometimes you just need to take office by the back of the process and shake it!
3. Have you made any changes to the [normal.dot file for word](http://www.pcdon.com/word-unstable-corrupted-normal-dot.html)?
4. Do you have any addons installed?

(1):"Utiliser Microsoft Office Word 2003 pour modifier des messages electroniques"

Comment: so. 
1) deleted, recreated.
2) turned off, sent a mail in text mode. receive in gmail with 0Kb wimail.dat, receive in outlook without attachments(however I believe outlook just does not display them, because mails arrives with the `X-MS-Has-Attach: yes` param).
2.1) Closed outlook. Restarted outlook. turned On(word as editor) send a mail in gmail. receive an 0kb winmail.dat.
2.2) sent a mail in HTML mode. receive in gmail with 2 attached images as usual, gif and png.
3. Yes, I modified normal.dot setting default font to Arial.
4. What do you mean? in Outlook AFAK - no...

Comment: Just did a quick googly, found this: http://news.cnet.com/look-out-outlook-gmail-adds-in-line-images/ (funny, but not an answer)
Have you set a signature using OWA by any chance? (it should be overridden by your client sig, but who knows)
You could run HiJackThis to remove BHO's.. might be malware.